# Unable to get boolean and variable value in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am building a sample project using React-Native. In this, I have a for loop with some values in array and onPress of Radio button I want to match that particular value with value of that for loop. when iterate for loop it matches every value with selected radiobutton value and I want to update state of  (showSubSegmentDropdown) to true but when loops get complete it get last matched value which gets false at the end.
Secondly, i want to push the values only when loop iteration value gets equal to clicked radio button value. But I am not getting the desired output.

```
this.state.value_parentSegID=[19, -1, 19, 19, 21, -1, 20, 22, -1]
this.state.value_SelectSegmentId          //Selected SegmentId onPress of RadioButton click
for(i=0;i<this.state.value_parentSegID.length;i++){
                                  
                                  if(this.state.value_SelectSegmentId===this.state.value_parentSegID[i]){
                                { this.setState({showSubSegmentDropdown:true})}
                                this.state.radioSubSegProps.push(this.state.SbsegmentNames[i])
                             
                                    console.log("true block mein ayaa",this.state.showSubSegmentDropdown)
                                    console.log("this.state.radioSubSegProps****",this.state.radioSubSegProps)
                                    continue;
                            //        console.log("this.setState({showSubSegmentDropdown:true})****",this.state.showSubSegmentDropdown)
                                  }else if(this.state.value_SelectSegmentId!==this.state.value_parentSegID[i]){
                                    { this.setState({showSubSegmentDropdown:false})}
                                  }
                                  
                                  console.log("this.setState({showSubSegmentDropdown:true})****",this.state.showSubSegmentDropdown)
                                }
```

**Any Solution Please?**

Comment: You speak of radio buttons, where's the render codes? and you not suppose to use .this.state.radioSubSegProps.push, you are suppose to use setState.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions, I assumed you want to know which of the options are selected.

Instead of looping you can in your function, you should explore onPress events in your radio button.

e.g.

```
const onPressFunction = (item) => {
   //do something with the selected item.
}

all_your_ids_array.map((item) => {
      return <RadioButton
        value={item}
        status={ checked ===  [19, -1, 19, 19, 21, -1, 20, 22, -1].indexOf(item)? 'checked' : 'unchecked' }
        onPress={() => onPressFunction(item)}
      />
})
```